Is using inline arrays a good idea?
Suppose I have a class which requires a small buffer of some value type. For example, it requires a buffer of four Int32s. I could declare a reference to an array that would fulfil this requirement, but recently I've discovered a relatively new C# feature: Inline Arrays.
My understanding is that when declaring an inline array, the raw data is allocated directly within the space for the containing type. As such, there would not be extra garbage collection required, and there are less issues with things such as cache misses.
However, I'm wondering if I'm being too clever for my own good and whether or not I should just stick with the standard array approach.
public class ExampleClass1
{
    private const int BufferSize = 4;

    private readonly int[] _buffer = new int[BufferSize];

    public ReadOnlySpan<int> GetBuffer() => _buffer;

    public void Update()
    {
        // Do something with the buffer
    }
}

public class ExampleClass2
{
    private const int BufferSize = 4;

    private DataBuffer _buffer;

    public ReadOnlySpan<int> GetBuffer() => _buffer;

    public void Update()
    {
        // Do something with the buffer
    }

    [InlineArray(BufferSize)]
    private struct DataBuffer
    {
        private int _firstElement;
    }
}

Are there any obvious downsides to using the second approach over the first? For context, this code is for a video game, and there will be many (hundreds, possibly thousands) of instances of the class at once.
From an inital glance there seems to be no functional difference between these approaches. But is there some deeper underlying problems that I'm overlooking?
EDIT - I'm not necessarily asking whether inline arrays would be faster. I've run some benchmarks, and the results seem to suggest that the inline array approach is slightly faster.
I'm asking if this approach would be a safe thing to do. Is there anything inherently dangerous about the inline approach? Would this potentially lead to bugs that I'm not foreseeing?

Have you profiled your two approaches? You cannot learn a billion hard and fast rules that will always be best. Instead, measure your scenarios and pick based on that.

I've run some benchmarks, and the results seem to suggest that the inline array approach is slightly faster. But that's not what I'm asking. My question asked if this was a good idea in general. Are there any problems with this approach, things that I'm overlooking that might lead to bugs?

Considering that the allocation of the containing object and the array will always be together, the only extra overhead is the extra size of the array reference. GC itself does not have any cost to objects which are not referenced, because GC Mark-Sweep will just skip them out completely in the Mark and remove them in bulk in the Sweep. If the objects are long-lived then every GC they live through introduces  a extra cost to track its lifetime.
